# Boost MPL sequences and default parameters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I'm currently stuck on C++03, so variadic templates don't work for me.

I can do what I want with a limited number of arguments using boost::mpl::vector and boost::mpl::inherit_linearly, but I want to do something similar to the following so the user doesn't have to deal with the mpl container directly:

```
template<class T, class A1, class A2 = void_, class A3 = void_>
class Foo : public FooHelper<T, boost::mpl::vector<A1, A2, A3>> {}
```

Is there a magic type I can use instead of void_ that vector will automatically interpret as a terminator for the defaulted template parameters? boost::mpl::void_ doesn't actually work, the sequence meta functions will iterate over it.

Right now I have a specialization that catches my own terminator class and makes it almost a no-op in the hierarchy, but I'd rather just have boost just treat the void_ entries as the end of the collection.

Comment: `mpl::vector` (and probably the other sequences) [seems to use](http://www.boost.org/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/plain/vector.hpp) `boost::mpl::na` to indicate that an element is not used.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. Can you promote this to an answer?